# How to animate views inside the Recycler View

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have an expandable, sectioned **RecyclerView** where clicking on a particular item adds a few items underneath it.

The section header rows have a down arrow which I then change to an up arrow if expanded. The default animation fades the entire section header row which is alright I guess.

How can I choose to animate the arrow 180 degrees when that row is clicked rather than just changing the image source to a different icon.
The more appropriate question would be: **Where** do I update this view inside the adapter? Which method? It doesn't always work when I try using **ObjectAnimators** in **`onCreateView()`** or in **`onBindViewHolder()`**.

Is there a better way/solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
animateListItem(view, prevPosition < position);
```

OR

```
setLayoutAnimation
```

in your adapter's **`getView`** OR **onBindViewHolder** method:

```
public static void setLayoutAnimation(Activity activity, ListView listView, Integer anim, int duration) {
  anim = (anim == null || anim == 0 ) ? R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom : anim;
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, anim);

  duration = duration <= 0 ? 500 : duration;
  animation.setDuration(duration);
  LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(animation, 1.0f);
  listView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
}

public static Animation slideFromTop, slideFromBottom;

public static void initAnim(Activity activity)
{
  slideFromTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.abc_slide_in_top);
  slideFromTop.setDuration(500);

  slideFromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
  slideFromBottom.setDuration(500);
}

public static void animateListItem(Activity activity, View view, boolean slideInBottom) {
  try {

    if (slideInBottom)
    {
      view.startAnimation(slideFromBottom);
    }
    else
    {
      view.startAnimation(slideFromTop);
    }

  } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```